# Custom choose intent with exclude my own activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have activity which set as default with action ACTION_VIEW in android manifest,I want to make activity receive the http,https etc url type of scheme to my application. see the code below

```
<activity
        android:name="com.test.ui.LinkLauncherActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

- Now from my application I have options for share the link, for that I
  want to open choose intent with selected application should only
  listed in the choose dialog exclude my own application.
- currently when I query to the package manger with action
  (ACTION_VIEW) It will return me the list of application In which I
  found my package name I just ignore it and open the choose intent but
  still it show me the my application in custom share intent dialog.
- **Is it due to of I define the category  as default in manifest as you see in above code ?**
- Let's share the custom intent code

  ```
  Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(mlm.getHitUrl());
  //get package manager
  PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

  Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uriUrl);

  List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(viewIntent, 0);

  List<LabeledIntent> intentList = new ArrayList<LabeledIntent>(resInfo.size() - 1); 

  for (int i = 0; i < resInfo.size(); i++) 
  {
      // Extract the label, append it, and repackage it in a LabeledIntent 
      ResolveInfo ri = resInfo.get(i);

      String packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;

      Log.d(getTag(),String.format("PackageName : %2s",packageName));

      if (!TextUtils.equals(packageName,"my application packageName")) {

          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uriUrl);
          intent.setPackage(packageName);
          intentList.add(new LabeledIntent(intent, packageName, ri.loadLabel(pm), ri.icon));
      }
  }

  // convert intentList to array 
  LabeledIntent[] extraIntents = intentList.toArray( new LabeledIntent[ intentList.size() ]);

  Intent openInChooser = Intent.createChooser(viewIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.intent_title_open_link));

  openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents);

  openInChooser.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

  startActivity(openInChooser);
  ```
- The above code still show me the my application in intent dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();

    String ext = file.getName().substring(file.getName().indexOf(".")+1);

    String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),type);

    PackageManager packageManager = activity.getPackageManager();

    List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

    String packageNameOfAppToHide = "com.test.app";

    ArrayList<Intent> targetIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();

    for (ResolveInfo currentInfo : activities) {

            String packageName = currentInfo.activityInfo.packageName;

        if (packageNameToHide.equals(packageName)) {

            Intent targetIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            targetIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),type);
            targetIntent.setPackage(packageName);
            targetIntents.add(targetIntent);
        }
    }
    if(targetIntents.size()>0) {

        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetIntents.remove(0), "Open file with");

        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[] {}));

        activity.startActivity(chooserIntent);
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "No app found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Where com.test.app is your application's package name.

Comment: I am not share for view file I share link(http) for view

Comment: how below code help if (packageNameToHide.equals(packageName)) {
 
            Intent targetIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 
            targetIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),type);
            targetIntent.setPackage(packageName);
            targetIntents.add(targetIntent);
        }

Comment: In this code, it is sending a uri. You can do anything with it as per your convenience.

Comment: I just want to exclude my package name, the code you share only include me application, i do not want to include my application in choose intent

Comment: Change the condition. SImple;

Comment: then see my share code :) It still show my application that is the question